# 2 levels nested routing in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I carefully read the docs of next routing system. 
It only mentions that I could achieve dynamic routing like this:

http://localhost:3000/level1/dynamicSlug

But I am trying to achive something like this:

http://localhost:3000/level1/level2/dynamicSlug

And I want level2 to be created dynamic too

Thanks so much !

Comment: you can simply create the folder structure like level1 -> level2 in page folder

Comment: @Wasif thanks you very much, but what I should do if I want that "level2" is dynamic, sorry my English

Comment: what do you want to achieve 
http://localhost:3000/level1/dynamicSlug1/dynamicSlug2?

Comment: @Wasif I want to have that level2 also dynamic, not by simply create a level2 folder, because data from backand reuqires level2 to be create dynamic

Comment: you can check out this https://github.com/zeit/next.js#custom-server-and-routing 
hope that helps

Answer (score 28):

It is possible to do nested scenarios according to your request in this way.
for example:

```
pages/
  level1/
    [dynamicSlug]/
      - index.js           // will match for /level1/1234
    level2/
      - index.js           // will match for /level1/level2
      - [dynamicSlug].js   // will match for /level1/level2/1234
```

Or

```
pages/
  level1/
    [dynamicSlug]/
      - index.js           // will match for /level1/1234
    level2/
      - index.js           // will match for /level1/level2
      [dynamicSlug]/
        - index.js         // will match for /level1/level2/1234
```

Comment: I believe [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68371678/static-pages-that-are-dynamically-generated-in-next-js) is a follow up to this. If you could give it a look I'd be forever grateful

Answer (score 5):

I know this is a bit of an old post, but I'd just like to share my working response with NextJS v11.

I want dynamic routing at two levels. E.g.:

- `{siteroot}/dynamicPage`
- `{siteroot}/dynamicUrlSection/dynamicPage`

My folder structure is:

- `/pages/[section]/[page].tsx`
- `/pages/[section]/index.tsx`

This way, the "dynamicPage" path at the root is handled by `index.tsx`, and nested routes are handled by `[page].tsx`

BONUS INFO: I am working with `Contentful` as a CMS. I use a single content model for all the pages at both levels.
The model has "section" and "page" properties.
The entries that serve the root dynamic pages (i.e. `/pages/[section]/index`) have a compound value in the "page" property of `{section}-index`.  I then have to be a bit smart in my client code:

```
if (!page) {
  page = `${section}-index`;
}

await fetchData(section, page);
```

Comment: Thank you. The docs don't seem to mention the ability to name folders with the`[slug]` for these kinds of routes.

Answer (score 4):

You have 2 choices:

1. Using v9 [`Dynamic Routing`](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes) by calling the folder as `[dynSlag]` and putting your page file inside.
2. Using [`custom server and routing`](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server), you will need to define a custom server, map your path to a specific next page.

Comment: Thanks I find the solution just create a folder named [ippage]

Comment: @felixmosh the 2nd link doesn't seem to work any longer

Answer (score 2):

Using the example right from the NextJs documentation, I use this hack, maybe you could use it.

```
<Link href="/posts/[id]" as={`/posts/${subFolder}${id}`}>
```

"as" will have a value like `/posts/nested_subfolder_file.md`

And in the `getPostData` function, just do this little change:

```
  const nestedPaths = id.split('_')
  const fileName = `${nestedPaths.pop()}.md`
  const fullPath = path.join(postsDirectory, ...nestedPaths, fileName)
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to have something working for my use case (rest API): http://localhost:3000/api/articles/1/highlights/2

Folder structure:

```
- articles
  - index.ts
  
  - [article_id]
    - index.ts
    
    - highlights
      - index.ts
      - [highlight_id].ts
```

[article_id]/index.ts file

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

const handler = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse): Promise<void> => {
  const { article_id } = req.query
  return res.status(200).json(`article: ${article_id}`);
};

export default handler;
```

highlights/[highlight_id].ts file

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

const handler = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse): Promise<void> => {
  const { highlight_id } = req.query
  return res.status(200).json(`highlight: ${highlight_id}`);
};

export default handler;
```