# Get current path in getStaticPaths nextjs

Tags: next.js, static-site-generation

I have some nested dynamic routes like so:

```
pages
  -- [path1]
    -- [path2]
  ...
```

where the paths for the path1 can be statically generated because they are always the same but for its child I first need to get the path1 (its parent) i'm not sure if i should use static generation but still is there a way to get the path inside `getStaticPaths` or is there a better approach to get a similar functionality?

(I do need to give a call to the server for both the paths)

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [nextjs nested dynamic folder routing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66036161/1870780)?