# Static pages that are dynamically generated in Next JS

Tags: next.js

Let's start with the relevant file structure

```
pages
  |---[state]
  |      |----[city].tsx
  |---[state].tsx
```

My goal is to both dynamically render pages at the location `/[state]` as well as at the location `/[state]/[city]`

When I run the build, `/[state]` is generated as expected but when it goes to build `[state]/city` it fails because `/[state]/` is now a dynamically assigned directory like `NorthCarolina/Charlotte` or `Florida/Orlando` and the error thrown is

`Error occured prerendering page "/NorthCarolina/Charlotte"... ENOTDIR: not a directory, open 'NorthCarolina/Charlotte'`

So while the errors seem kinda reasonable, I'm trying to figure out how I'm supposed to generate all these pages I want dynamically.

I tried a hack solution like adding a folder called `NorthCarolina` to see if that'd fix it but no luck.

---

---

Figured out that it has to do with how I'm writing to a file in `getStaticPaths` and reading from the written files in `getstaticProps`. Still messing around with it but the problem isn't related to a next.js feature.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer for posterity.

The problem was that when I was using `fs.writeFile` in `getStaticPaths` I was writing to `/tmp/Florida/Tampa` which doesn't exist. What is valid is writing to `/tmp/FloridaTampa`.

Coding can be painful.