# Next.js dynamic route

Tags: typescript, next.js

after searching half a day and testing I really need to ask.

I load dynamic content from api, never know how many or what id.

I want to create a dynamic structure for pages

'www.domain.com' which will load the index page

'www.domain.com/eth' where eth is a query parameter 'chain' and loads the [chain].tsx page.

'www.domain.com/eth/uni' adding query parameter 'dex' and loads the [chain][dex].tsx page.

'www.domain.com/eth/0xr83urt36sdt45t' or have a query parameter tokenAddress and loads the [chain][tokenAddress].tsx page.

I know for example that dexscreener.com is doing this, but I can not figure out how this works. I am using nextjs with typescript and I am fairly new to both.

anyone that could point me to the right direction/ folder structure etc. That would be awesome.

Comment: www.domain.com/[chain]/[dex] or www.domain.com/[chain]/[pairAddress] this should be possible right? how else would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple layers to this question:

1. routing to the [chain] page
2. routing to the [chain][dex] page
3. also matching [chain][token] page

This is accomplished via Dynamic Routes as outlined [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#caveats)

> Predefined routes take precedence over dynamic routes, and dynamic routes over catch all routes. Take a look at the following examples:

> pages/post/create.js - Will match /post/create

> pages/post/[pid].js - Will match /post/1, /post/abc, etc. But not /post/create

> pages/post/[...slug].js - Will match /post/1/2, /post/a/b/c, etc. But not /post/create, /post/abc

Similarly, You could first statically define [chain] routes. For example, if you wish to support a handful of chains, you could make a page for that chain route (eth, sol, etc.). This could also be dynamic with a [chain] pattern (as shown in example 2).

Then, for matching [chain][dex/token] to the same route: it  can be accomplished via using the [...slug] method to pull the entire route and parse out the relevant chain/dex/token or via nested dynamic routes (more info in this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57648690/2-levels-nested-routing-in-nextjs)) Both would allow you to use the above pattern to match any route which is a [chain][dex/token] pattern. This way, both the dex and token patterns are routed similarly (as dexscreener does it).

Once on that route, you could use `getStaticProps` or `getServerSideProps` to check if it is a dex or token (via your own dictionary) and load the appropriate content on the page.

Comment: Thanks that makes things more clear. if using [...slug] how to differentiate between [chain][dex] and [chain][pairAddress] and would I make a page like [chain][slug].tsx or how? or is it on the folder I use [...slug] with index.tsx and filter there what slug has been used

Comment: As [...slug] will give you the entire path, you'd need to write your own logic in getStaticProps/getServerSideProps for SSR or on page load to determine what that route is referencing. Simple implementation may be to split the slug address string on '/' and checking whether the route ending is a dex or pairAddress (you'd need to check that against some dictionary) and calling the appropriate api route/displaying content

Comment: And the following link (i shared above) explains 2nd layer dynamic routing via Next: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57648690/2-levels-nested-routing-in-nextjs